# iPhone - XCode 4 linker error with no method call nor object use

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction, linker, compiler-errors

I have a project that includes a shared library as source files.
Some of the library classes need the include of some Frameworks (like the known Apple Reachability).
Those Frameworks are not included into the project because I don't use the classes / methods that needs them.
I have a MyStandardLib.h that references all the library headers, and that is included in the.pch on my app.

But...

When building my app, the linker generates link error for those objects I don't use/call in the app So they should logicaly not be linked.

[image]

As an example, if I remove from the project the incriminated classes and Frameworks, everything works fine.

If I add the needed Frameworks :

- It's crazy to do that for each project because of classes I won't use
- It increases my app file size for nothing useful (26 Ko -> 1.2 Mo)

How can I avoid those linker error, and avoid links that should not happen :

- keeping my library as is in the project (I don't want a precompiled library)
- Not needing to include all those useless Frameworks until I really need them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for those errors are clearly because the frameworks you are including in your project do require those other frameworks (from what you could provide they use: [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/index.html), the [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) Framework and the [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) Framework)

What is happening is that when the compile **links** your objects (in the compiler sense of it) it is also looking for objects *'mentioned'* in your added frameworks and it is not finding them because they have not been included to your projects.

If you use a Framework A that is linked with Framework B then if you application C uses framework A it also needs framework B because frameworks are not exactly self contained.

If your code compile without those frameworks and your application needs to take low space simply remove them from your Build Phase and you'll be good to go.

However, if it doesn't compile without those frameworks you will have no choice but to include them in your project and, therefore, increasing even more the final space required by your application.

Comment: OK, but my application DO NOT use framework A nor framework B. It's just a source file, which content is not used, taht need a framework A.